# Combining audio and video streams in m3u8 playlist, audio stops working

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming, playlist, m3u8, mpeg-dash

I need to combine separate audio and video streams into one playlist. I did it, but I have a problem. After a random time, the audio stops playing, or very rarely, the audio is OK, but freezes the video. Audio and video sources are links to a third-party server, and when I test the sources separately, everything works fine.

Here are my playlist files:

**audio.m3u8**

```
#EXTM3U

#EXTINF:190,audio
https://third-party-server.com/audio-url

#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

**video.m3u8**

```
#EXTM3U

#EXTINF:190,video
https://third-party-server.com/video-url

#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

**main.m3u8**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:5

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",NAME="merge",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="audio.m3u8"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=646043,CODECS="opus,avc1.4d401e,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x360,AUDIO="audio"
video.m3u8

#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Information about the sources:

audio:
bitrate: 144209, 
audioSampleRate: 48000, 
codecs: "opus",

video:
resolution: 640x360, 
bitrate: 646043, 
codecs: "avc1.4d401e",

Both sources have the same duration: 190 seconds

I experimented a lot. I used sources with other qualities (the server allows you to get many formats), I changed "BANDWIDTH", tried other codecs. But nothing helped, my audio still stops working. Also, when I test one source, I can use rewind, but the combined playlist stops working when I try to rewind.

It all looks like a buffering problems, but I haven't found a way how to configure this in m3u8.

I will be glad to hear your advice.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** You're missing the tag `#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:190` in the audio and video playlists. I'm not sure if this would fix your issue, but it fixed mine. See below for more info.

**Long answer**

Although this question is more than 2 years old, I was trying to do the same thing. I downloaded [Apple's HLS Tools](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/using_apple_s_http_live_streaming_hls_tools) and used their validator tool and kept getting the error `Error: Max extinf duration of 1746 more than 2 * target duration 0`. I didn't know what to do with that error message, so I got video file and ran the `mediafilesegmenter` which splits the video file into smaller files and generates a m3u8 playlist.

I saw that the new playlist had the `#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION` tag and I figured I'd try it and it worked.

Hopefully that helps anyone else having issues with this.